# openshift "www" directory?

Tags: php, ftp, openshift, filezilla, openshift-client-tools

My openshift rhc client is not working so i again use [Filezilla FTP to acess my openshift](https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/)

Past year i use filezilla then "www" directory found at `/var/lib/openshift/54216b58500444bb9d0009d0/app-root/repo/php/` But now there no such structure exist i think may openshift change directory structure.
My question is where i upload my code? so that my scalable app work seamless

Answer (score 2):

You can find the path to your code by looking at OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR environment variable. So doing an `echo $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` should print the path to your code.

But please remember that the only directory that is persistent accross deployments is the data directory (*OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR*). Any change you make in other place will be lost on your next deployment.

Read more about [directory variables](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#directory-variables).

Comment: hi Alexandru Till now i doess't upload any code i.e this is new app where i upload?

Comment: Well, the code lives under `/app-root/repo/`, but I did not test openshift using only ftp so I don't know how nice plays with FTP. And on a side note, you don't really need rhc client to update your code. [You just need git](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-modifying-applications.html) and when you push all your changes becomes live.